# What is the best way to extend SQLAlchemy so that I can filter the results that are returned in a query?

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, sqlalchemy-utils

I am new to SQLAlchemy.  What I need to do is to post process the results that are returned from a query.  I would need to (at the client side) look at the results of a specific column and alter the value based on a condition.  What would be the best way to extend/modify SQLAlchemy to do this?